# BQ script getting failed in composer

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-composer, bq

I am trying to run one bq script using bigquery.Client
but getting below error,

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got string literal

```
    v_minus_statement_s_t="DECLARE dummy_key DEFAULT to_hex(sha256('*nik'));
    DECLARE dummy_value DEFAULT '*nik';
    DECLARE currency_value DEFAULT '$';
    select
    to_hex(sha256(cast(ID as string))) as dw__id,
    to_hex(sha256(cast(ID as string))) as dw_sub_id
    from voice"
    op =client.query(v_minus_statement_s_t).to_dataframe()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps post the code that is failing in addition to the error message being logged?

Comment: try adding ; to the select too.